# Attached Property + Style -> ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles

I have created a very Simple attached Property:

```
public static class ToolBarEx 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedExProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "FocusedEx", typeof(bool?), typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FocusedExChanged));

    private static void FocusedExChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is ToolBar)
        {
            if (e.NewValue is bool)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    (d as ToolBar).Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool? GetFocusedEx(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(FocusedExProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFocusedEx(DependencyObject obj, bool? value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FocusedExProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Setting this in Xaml works perfectly fine, but if I try setting it within a Style:

I receive an ArguemntNullException during the Runtime (saying: "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: property").

I cannot figure what is wrong here. Any hint is appriciated!

Comment: When you get an exception look at the stack trace. That should help you locate where your code fails. If you still cannot solve the problem then please post the stacktrace here together with your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A common mistake made when registering attached dependency properties is to incorrectly specify the `ownerType` argument. This must always be the registering class, `ToolBarEx` here:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedExProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FocusedEx", typeof(bool?), typeof(ToolBarEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FocusedExChanged));
```

And just for avoiding unnecessary code in the property changed handler you could safely cast `NewValue` to `bool`:

```
private static void FocusedExChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var toolBar = d as ToolBar;
    if (toolBar != null && (bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        toolBar.Focus();
    }
}
```